# Turning math expressions into Java code

Tags: java

1. (3-k /4 )^2
2. 9x-(4.5+y)/2x

How do I go about translating them into Java code expressions? My book examples are not helping as much.

Answer (score 2):

Most of it already is a Java expression. The only parts that aren't are:

1. The `^` operator, by which you presumably mean exponentiation. Any written expression of the form *x<sup>y</sup>* is expressed in Java as

   ```
   Math.pow(x, y)
   ```
2. The elision of multiplication operators. `2x` is expressed in Java (and all other programming languages I've ever used except assembler) as `2*x`.

Comment: public class Math 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        double k = stdIn.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(Math.pow(3-k/4,2)); 
    }
}

Comment: So I put that in but the pow part came up as an error...Did I do something wrong.?

Comment: You called your class `Math`, so you couldn't find `java.lang.Math.pow()`. Call your class something else.

Comment: Or just fully qualify the name as `java.lang.Math`.

Answer (score -1):

One simple way is to parse it recursively in regard to the operators.

A mathematic expression like 9x-(4.5+y)/2x is made of three parts: **operand1 operator operand2** where operand1 itself is a mathematical expression and operand2 is also a mathematical expression

In parsing it you should consider also operators priorities

Comment: If he was having difficulty parsing it, this wouldn't answer the question. But he is asking something else.

Comment: Ya! his own Math class has hidden the access to java's

Comment: I changed it but I am still coming up with an error.. public class testExpression 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        double k = stdIn.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(Math.pow("3-k = " / (4)^2));
    }
}

Comment: @AbNegusu Don't post comments under this pointless answer, and 'coming up with an error' isn't a problem description. But where did you get the quotes from?

Comment: @Ab Negusu. What are you trying to do exactly? Are you trying to learn how to write mathematical expressions in Java, or do you have a further goal?